# AngularFire Duplicate Prevention

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I am working on a project where I am pushing classes to firebase and I want to be able to make this as efficient as possible. Lets say my data looks like the following

```
  -Classes
    -classKey1
      -startTime: ---
      -endTime: ---
      -Instructor: ---
    -classKey2
      -startTime: ---
      -endTime: ---
      -Instructor: ---
```

Now when I go to push another class into the database I would like to be able check to make sure a class just like it doesn't exist already. If one does exist I would like to grab its key to use somewhere else. I have been trying everything i can think of and nothing will work. If any one has any ideas please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything? What's your current code for pushing these values?

Comment: Also, if a key already exists and you set its value, you will overwrite what's in there. There will be no duplicates.

Comment: Some of the things I've tried is subscribing to the firebaselistobservable then trying to compare the results and see if any match what I am going to try to push or not. Then if I do find a match it use that match values key. I have tried filtering the observable, which wasn't working. For pushing the data I am just using the function that angularfire gives, so each time I am pushing a random key is generated. That's why I'm having trouble because if I just did another push the keys would be different but the children would all be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of subscribing those items and searching yourself is the key..

Try it like this:

```js
export class EntityModel {
   $key: string;
   $exists: () => {};

   startTime: Date = new Date();
   endTime: Date = new Date();
   Instructor: string = '';
}

@Injectable()
export class YourService {

   public entities: EntityModel[];

   private _authState: FirebaseAuthState;

   constructor(private _af: AngularFire) {
      _af.auth.subscribe(authState => {
         this._authState = authState;

         if (authState) {
            _af.database.list('/classes').subscribe(classes => {
               this.entities = classes;
            });
         }
      });
   }

   public add(entity: EntityModel) {
      if (!entity) return console.log('invalid entity!');

      if (this._authState) {
         entity.Instructor = this._authState.uid;
      }

      // trying to find an existing one ..
      const existing = this.entities &&
         this.entities.length &&
         this.entities.find(e =>
            e.startTime == entity.startTime &&
            e.endTime == entity.endTime &&
            e.Instructor == entity.Instructor
         );
      if (existing) {
         // we found one ..
         console.log('FOUND:', existing.$key);
         return;
      }

      delete entity.$exists;

      // update or create?
      if (entity.$key) {
         // update ..
         const key = entity.$key; // temporary save our key!
         delete entity.$key; // we dont want to push this into our firebase-database ..
         this._af.database.list('/classes').update(key, entity); // update entry
      }
      else {
         // create ..
         this._af.database.list('/classes').push(entity);
      }
   }
}
```